# Using view binding, can you define the type parameters for a generic View subclass?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

The [view binding feature](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) that was added in Android Studio 3.6 obviates the need for the clunky `findViewById` mechanism.

However, if I'm not mistaken, it doesn't yet support a way of declaring the **type parameters** for generics.

Consider the following View class:

```java
/**
 * Spinner that calls toString() on choices to represent them in the UI.
 */
public class Spinner<T> extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner {

    // ...

    private List<T> items;

    private int selectedItemIndex;

    public void setItems(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public T getSelectedItem() {
        return items.get(selectedItemIndex);
    }

}
```

Now if my code contains something like the following:

```java
List<Foobar> foobars = getFoobarListFromSomewhere();
views.foobarSpinner.setItems(foobars);
```

Then Android Studio will show me an unchecked warning such as:

```
Unchecked call to 'setItems(Collection<T>)' as a member of raw type 'org.example.views.Spinner'
```

And the only way around it seems to be to add `//noinspection unchecked`, or to cast `view.foobarSpinner` to another variable that has the correctly parametrized type, which is very cumbersome.

Is there currently any cleaner way around this problem?

Comment: How does layout inflater provide generic type parameter in the first place? Pretty sure (non-abstract) view classes should not be generic.

Comment: @Pawel I believe the inflater doesn't need to care about this since type parameters don't exist at runtime.